# Is it possible to move crusor up & down in wrapped long line in Vi?

Tags: vim, long-lines

I have this question in my head for quite a while since I started to use vi.

I know that vi can wrap the long line into a nice block, but is there a fast way for us to move 'up' or 'down' in the block (so we dont have to use right/left arrow key and spend 30sec to get to the place we want)?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just precede your movement command with "g" to ignore the line wrap, eg:

To move down:

```
gj
```

To move up:

```
gk
```

Also once you're on the right line, then using `b` and `w` to move word-by-word is faster than going character-by-character with the left and right arrows.

Comment: To expand on this, you could add `nnoremap k gk` and `nnoremap j gj` to your .vimrc, so that you don't have to notice that you're trying to move on a wrapped line. With those mappings, `j` and `k` will always move as desired on a wrapped line.